# Conditional HTML with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is the code:

```
tr.row(ng-class="{editing: is_dirty(p)}" ng-repeat="p in persons")
 td {{p.name}}
 td {{p.surname}} 

 if is_dirty(p)
   button.action Save
 else
   button.action Edit
   button.action Delete
```

I am starting with my interface, will try to implement some inline editing. So the first step in this is that I list all persons, and on click I add a new row. Now, a new row should only have the save button, existing rows would have an edit and a delete button.

The above code does not work (using jade, express, node and angular).
I've looked at `ng-switch` and `ng-if` but they look overly complex to me for a simple if else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is_dirty(p) is a method available in your scope, you can use

```
ng-show="is_dirty(p)"
```

or

```
ng-hide="is_dirty(p)"
```

ng-show will display the element when is_dirty returns true.
ng-hide will hide the element when is_dirty returns true.

ng-if is similar to ng-show, but the element will be destroyed from the dom instead of being hidden when the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<ANY ng-switch="expression">
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue1">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue2">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default>...</ANY>
</ANY>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Comment: yes and it looked a bit too verbose to me..I like Galdo's answer better. Thanks!